# How to set specific starting date in Month Calendar C# manually

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2015, date-formatting, monthcalendar

I am beginner in c#
I want to create a month calendar from 1AD to 5000 or 9999AD.
But I have a question, how can I set starting date in calendar. For example, I want to set my date 1 to Friday and other dates will follow it, how can I do the same. Please help me

Comment: You need to be more clear on what you want to do. C# already has a `DateTime` struct on .Net Framework ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) . Is it not enough to fulfill your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Please Go through the following links. You have to understand the calendar structure first

> http://www.kettic.com/winforms_ui/csharp_guide/calendar_structure.shtml

How to add selected and special days to the calendar at design time

> http://www.kettic.com/winforms_ui/csharp_guide/calendar_get_started.shtml

Comment: Ok Daisy my question is I want to make a calendar manually. How can I? Hope now you can understand what I actually want. I already told I am beginner in c#, and if title is not let you clear my intention, I did reply what I actually want just before of your comment. I hope now you can understand what I want actually  help me if you can 

Comment: https://authormayanksaxena.blogspot.com/2018/06/calendar-from-year-1-to-year-9999.html